# 500 Error after Dreamhost server upgrade

Tags: error, server, hosting

Dreamhost upgraded my VPS overnight and I immediately got a 500 error. The site currently works on another Dreamhost VPS (the original below) and an Arcustech server.

**After checking the error logs I'm receiving this error:**

```
AH01215: php73.cgi: unable to extent pixel cache `No such file or directory' @ fatal/cache.c/CacheSignalHandler/3626.: /dh/cgi-system/php73.cgi
```

**The server was upgraded from:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

to:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.12 (stretch)
Release:    9.12
Codename:   stretch
```

I've done the following to try to resolve it

1. Deleted composer.lock & vendor/ and reinstalled everything.
2. Started a fresh directory and change the site to run out of that directory
   restarted the MySql VPS, and VPS
3. Deleted mysqlVPS and VPS, the ordered a fresh build of both, reinstalling node, composer, etc.and rebuilding the site there

Dreamhost was ...uh...less than helpful on the matter.

Has anyone ever seen this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Dreamhost was ...uh...less than helpful on the matter.

That's always been my experience with them.

Best I can tell (from https://github.com/the-paperless-project/paperless/issues/98 which has a similar error message) that error is coming from Imagick.

Whether it's a bug in Imagick (possible) or Dreamhost has misconfigured it on the VPS (more likely), it's hard to say, but either way, they should be looking into it.

Comment: Basically, they said they can't do anything about it. Said Imagick is installed correctly.

I have the same site on 3 different servers:

1. https://scalecomputing.com DREAMHOST (works fine) - Imagick 3.4.3RC1 (ImageMagick 6.7.7-10)
2. http://scale.rocks (works fine) ARCUSTECH - Imagick 3.4.4 (ImageMagick 6.9.10-23)
3. http://myscale.it (500 error) DREAMHOST - Imagick 3.4.4 (ImageMagick 6.9.7-4)

Comment: Eww... might be worth finding a new host for that site?

Comment: Yea, I think I'm going to. Thanks for replying and letting me know I wasn't crazy. I saw that link you shared before creating this thread, but I just wanted to tap the community to see if they've ever had similar issues.